# Posting to someone else Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive API on Android to post pictures to the same drive. But I'm curious, I want to have a Public Folder where anybody can post to, without the need to send them the "Share Link". Is that possible?

For Example, I have a Public Folder on my Google Drive. Users of my App, will posts their images to my Google Drive Folder, instead of posting the images to their drive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Drive is generally for direct user-to-user sharing. Could you clarify what the public folder would be used for? Unfortunately the Drive Android API doesn't have sharing capabilities at the moment, but the Java API Client Library might be able to support your use case.

Comment: For example, let's say that your company has an Hotel, then when people uses the app and takes pictures from that App. They'll have the chance to upload that picture on the Hotel's Drive Folder

Answer (score 0):

You can do that pretty much anywhere like Facebook or Instagram or Google photos, etc... I cannot delete my Google drive and all I receive in it is pornography that I don't want to look at, I don't want my kids looking at on my phone thinking I'm doing this stuff I mean come on they should at least give you the option to delete a Google drive if you're not using it.